# base64 decode null reference excpetion on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have this code on my cs page that takes decodes a key from my Url string. The key is "Reauth_URL" and its a link that is decoded in base64 to UTF8.

```
////base 64 decoding for Reauth_URL key in URL query string
    string encodedString =     Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Reauth_URL"]).Trim(')');
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

I'm trying to use decodedString but i keep on getting a null refence exception but i can see that the key and value are there.

once i can return the string value id like to ba able to send it into a hyperlink that's on my aspx page.

the encoded url is set up from IronPort which allows a user to lg in as differnt user if they've been blocked from a website. so this reauth_url key in the query string allows them to log in as different user. by the reauth_url needs to be decoded and linked to the hyperlink. I know the key and value is there but i cant get by this null exception, and when i say i know they are there obviously i don't mean in the code above, ive had to split the url query by ? and & and print it out somewhere else and they exist. The code below is used earlier and the key and value i need is there.

```
string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
    txtBlockedUrl.Visible = true;
    string [] result = currentUrl.Split(new  Char[]{'?','&'});

    foreach (string r in result)
    {
        txtBlockedUrl.Text += HttpUtility.UrlDecode(r) + "\n";
    }

div style="font-size: medium">
    <a href="<%=decodedString%>" style="text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;">LogIn as Different User</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you debug step by step through this code, you have to see on which line it occur.

Comment: right at the first line asking for the parameter of reauth_url it already null, but if do a request.params['reuth_url'] to a general label for debugging it pops up and then take it and go to a decoder website and paste the encoded string in and decode it the decoded url shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended Up doing this....

```
//splitting url string for textbox using name value collection
    NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
    string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
    string [] result = currentUrl.Split('&');
    foreach (string r in result)
    {
        string[] parts = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(r).Split('=');
        if (parts.Length > 0)
        {
            string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
            string val = parts[1].Trim();

            collection.Add(key, val);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Reauth_URL"]` is null, `Convert.ToString` will throw a null reference exception.

Please note that the [Params indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx) will return `null` when "Reauth_URL" is not available.
So you have to check first if it exists: (what if the url does not provide it?)

```
string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Reauth_URL"];
if (value!=null) {
    string encodedString = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Reauth_URL"]).Trim(')');
    //...
```